# dynamic SQL execution and saving the result in flat file in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I want to create a SSIS package which writes a file with data generated by executing a SQL Statement. This generic package will be invoked by other packages passing in correct SQL as a variable.

Thus in the generic package :

I want to execute a dynamic SELECT query and fetch dynamic number of columns from a single database instance, the connection string does not per call and store the result into a flat file.

What would be an ideal way to accomplish this in SSIS.

**What I tried  :**

The simplest solution that I could find was a writing a script task which would open a SQL connection , execute the SQL using SQLCommand, populate a datatable using the data fetched and write the contents directly to the file system using System.io.File and Release the connection.

I tried using OLE Database source with the SQLsupplied by a variable (with Validation set to false) and directing the rows into a Flat file connection. However due to the dynamic number and names of the columns I ran into errors.

Is there a more standard way of achieving this without using a script task?

Answer (score 0):

How about this ... concatenate all field values into one field, and map AllFields to a field in a text file destination.

SELECT [f1]+',' + [f2] AS AllFields FROM [dbo].[A]

All of the "other"packages will know how to create the correct SQL. Their only contract with the "generic" package would be to eventually have only one field nameed "AllFields".

Comment: I also want to store the result generated from the SQL in a flat file. The solution you provided takes care of just the first part of the problem.

Comment: You can have the destination flat file defined with only one field - AllFields. Thus, you will have only one field in the source as well as destination. Size of the AllFields can be set varchar(4000) or varchar(max). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, I do not think there is a "standard" way to do this.  I believe the solution from Anoop would work well and while I have not tested the idea I wish I would have investigated it before writing my own solution.  You should not need a script task in that solution...

In any case, I did write my own way to generate csv files from SQL tables that may run up against edge cases and need polishing but works rather well right now.  I am looping through multiple tables before this task so the CurrentTable variable can be replaced with any variable you want.

Here is my code:

```
public void Main()
    {
        string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        try
        {
            string TableName = Dts.Variables["User::CurrentTable"].Value.ToString();
            string FileDelimiter = ",";
            string TextQualifier = "\"";
            string FileExtension = ".csv";



            //USE ADO.NET Connection from SSIS Package to get data from table
            SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
            myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["connection manager name"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);



            //Read data from table or view to data table
            string query = "Select * From [" + TableName + "]";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myADONETConnection);
            //myADONETConnection.Open();
            DataTable d_table = new DataTable();
            d_table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            //myADONETConnection.Close();



            string FileFullPath = Dts.Variables["$Project::ExcelToCsvFolder"].Value.ToString() + "\\Output\\" + TableName + FileExtension;

            StreamWriter sw = null;
            sw = new StreamWriter(FileFullPath, false);

            // Write the Header Row to File
            int ColumnCount = d_table.Columns.Count;
            for (int ic = 0; ic < ColumnCount; ic++)
            {
                sw.Write(TextQualifier + d_table.Columns[ic] + TextQualifier);
                if (ic < ColumnCount - 1)
                {
                    sw.Write(FileDelimiter);
                }
            }
            sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

            // Write All Rows to the File
            foreach (DataRow dr in d_table.Rows)
            {
                for (int ir = 0; ir < ColumnCount; ir++)
                {
                    if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[ir]))
                    {
                        sw.Write(TextQualifier + dr[ir].ToString() + TextQualifier);
                    }
                    if (ir < ColumnCount - 1)
                    {
                        sw.Write(FileDelimiter);
                    }
                }
                sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

            }

            sw.Close();

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }



        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // Create Log File for Errors
            //using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Dts.Variables["User::LogFolder"].Value.ToString() + "\\" +
            //    "ErrorLog_" + datetime + ".log"))
            //{
            //    sw.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
            //}

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            throw;
        }


        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```